# ldap_mod_add or ldap_add not for add new account in LDAP Server

Tags: php, server, ldap

Anyone know about add new account in LDAP Server with php script? 
if i search in google, the answer always this function ldap_add or ldap_mod_add, but that i know the function just add the attributes like ldap_mod_add. i just search php function not ad2ldap or either.

anyone know how to add new account in LDAP Server?

and here my code :

```
/**
* new release
*/

public static function addNewAccountWithauthForAdmin($user,$attributes=array(),$attributes_val=array(),$user_auth,$password_auth){
    $userdata = array();
    $userdn = "CN=".$user.",OU=USERS,OU=CORP,DC=domain,DC=corp"; print $userdn;
    $user_auth = self::userDomainName($user_auth);
    $password_auth = base64_decode($password_auth);
    $is_arrayaction = (is_array($attributes) AND is_array($attributes_val)) AND (count($attributes) == count($attributes_val)) ? true : false;
    if($is_arrayaction){
        $action = array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($attributes);$i++){
            $userdata[$attributes[$i]] = $attributes_val[$i];   
            // Output $userdata : {"ipphone":"1825","mail":"nomail@mail.com"}
        }
        $action[$i] = ldap_mod_add(self::authForChangeAttr($user_auth,$password_auth),$userdn,$userdata);
        return $action;
    }

    $userdata[$attributes] = $attributes_val;
    // Output $userdata : {"ipphone":"1825"}
    $action = ldap_mod_add(self::authForChangeAttr($user_auth,$password_auth),$userdn,$userdata) ? true : false;

    return $action;
}
```

thanks
ik

Answer (score 1):

- `ldap_mod_add` Allows you to add an attribute to an entry which already exists
- `ldap_add` Allows you to add an entry to the directory

`ldap_add` requires 3 parameters :

- `link_identifier` : result of the `ldap_connect` function
- `dn` : The dn of the entry to add
- `entry` : Which is an array representing the entry. It needs to have all the attributes to perform the `ldapadd` operation (in the LDAP way), ie., you have to set :

  - The required object classes

    ```
    ["objectClass"]=["Top","person","organizationalPerson","user"];
    ```
  - The mandatory attributes specified by the objectclasses

    See this for the objectClass user : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683980(v=vs.85).aspx

You can also find a sample code here : https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/458770-adding-users-to-ad-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - works for me

```
            $ds = ldap_connect("ldaps://example.org");
            if ($ds) {
                $r = ldap_bind($ds, "userAdmin", "adminPSW");
                $dn = 'CN=username,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=org';
                $pwdtxt="password";
                ## Create Unicode password
                $newPassword = "\"" . $pwdtxt . "\"";
                $len = strlen($newPassword);
                $newPassw = "";
                for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
                    $newPassw .= "{$newPassword{$i}}\000";
                }
                $ldaprecord['cn'] = "username";
                $ldaprecord['mail'] = "mail@example.org";
                $ldaprecord['ipphone'] = "0123456789";
                ldap_add($ds, $dn, $ldaprecord);
                $encodedPass = array('unicodepwd' => $newPassw);
                ldap_mod_replace ($ds, $dn, $encodedPass);
            }
            $res = ldap_error ($ds);
            if( $res=="Success"){
            ##Success
            }
            ldap_close($ds);
```